# Compressed images not compressed front-end

Tags: image, joomla, compression

I have compressed my images from 80-300 kbs back to 4-12 kbs in https://tinypng.com/ and replaced them in the joomla library (3.6.5), they keep the same size when inside the library, but when downloading from the front-end they are back to their original size.

The tool https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights still gives the same message that my images are too big and show the new compressed images with their old sizes.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If Google's PageSpeed tool didn't show the same old images, it might have been a local caching problem. However, since it shows the bigger file sizes, that can be eliminated as possible cause.

Therefore: Your server still has the old (uncompressed) images. Your error was with the upload / replacing of those images.

A bit of background to find the root cause: Unlike some other CMS systems, Joomla does not touch the images when serving a page. They are stored on your webserver exactly as served to the client, and are served by Apache (or whatever other webserver you might be running). You can use an FTP client to check the file sizes directly.